# Using Spring Cloud Kubernetes, how do I get the instanceId of the running instance

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I have a microservice written in Spring Boot and leveraging Spring Cloud Kubernetes that runs in Kubernetes as follows:

- a Kubernetes service (`foo-service`)
- two instances of `foo-service` (pods) sitting behind the service, each running the Spring Boot application

I can list *all* of the instances of the service by using the Spring Cloud Kubernetes `DiscoveryClient` as follows:

```
List<ServiceInstance> allInstances = discoveryClient.getInstances("foo-service")
```

How do I get the instanceId of the instance that is executing this code?

Comment: I am a little bit confused by "currently running instance"... can you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: I'm looking for the identifier of the instance of `foo-service` on which this code is executing.

Comment: you mean the actual pod where some code is executing? Im sorry, but why would that matter to you?

Answer (score 0):

The instance name is the name of the Pod, the name of the pod is the same as the hostname.

So for example use

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
```

Comment: wasn't the question: _how to get it_ that name, actually, where the code is executing? But to be fair, I was really confused about the question too

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similar, yet different approach, going for the ip address:

```
ServiceInstance myInstance = discoveryClient.getInstances(serviceId)
    .find(instance -> {
        instance.host == InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostAddress
    })
```

Works for me.